# Function in node.js always return undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm new at nodejs, and of course I see some guides/screencast to learn a little bit; but I'm very stoked about async/sync, read files and how nodejs handle the callbacks/returns. For example, I can't return the variable from this request query:

```
function call (method, parameters){
    fs.readFile("./cache/session", function(err, data){
        var pieces = data.toString().split(),
        sessionid = (method != "createsession") ? "/" + pieces[0] : "",
        vars = (!parameters) ? "/" + parameters : "",
        endpoint = "http://rest.svc/" + method + "json/";

        request({ url: endpoint}, function(error, response, body){
            if(!error) 
                return body;
        })
    })
}
```

'On the paper', I mean on javascript this will work perfectly, but in node always returns an `undefined`, I read other posts on stackoverflow about this, but no one  clarifies me much as it should be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using you an Asynchronous functions, like `call` requires you to pass a callback parameter into the function, then the parameters of the callback is your "return" because the asynchronous function will return (undefined) before your `fs.readFile` responds.

```
function call (method, parameters, callback){
    fs.readFile("./cache/session", function(err, data){
     var pieces = data.toString().split(),
     sessionid = (method != "createsession") ? "/" + pieces[0] : "",
     vars = (!parameters) ? "/" + parameters : "",
        endpoint = "http://rest.svc/" + method + "json/";

        request({ url: endpoint}, function(error, response, body){
         if(!error) 
                callback(body)
        })
    })
}
```

Comment: This makes the "call" function asynchronous as well, which may or may not be desired. See my answer with futures for a way to keep the "call" function synchronous

Comment: I wasn't are they requested this be done synchronously, I think this is what they were asking for.

Comment: It wasn't specified in the question, so our answers give two different approaches. Which one is desired is up to the asker to choose in each situation it is needed.

Comment: Thanks - The idea are doing it async. All I need was to understand how the callback function works. Now, the code has finished, thanks: http://jsfiddle.net/8udk6uth/2/.

Answer (score 1):

In the function "call()", you start an asynchronous task. When that task has started, the function just continues. There is nothing else to do, so it returns undefined.

Now, when the asyncronous task calls it's callback, the callback doesn't really have anywhere to return the value, so it is discarded.

To get around this, you need to use something called Futures or Promises. I have never used these before myself, but they work something like this:

```
function call (method, parameters){
    var future = new Future();
    fs.readFile("./cache/session", function(err, data){
        var pieces = data.toString().split(),
        sessionid = (method != "createsession") ? "/" + pieces[0] : "",
        vars = (!parameters) ? "/" + parameters : "",
        endpoint = "http://rest.svc/" + method + "json/";

        request({ url: endpoint}, function(error, response, body){
            if(!error) 
                future.return(body);
            else
                future.throw(error);
        });
    });
    return future.wait();
};
```

Comment: I presume you mean this npm packages? - https://www.npmjs.com/package/future - https://www.npmjs.com/package/promise

Comment: Probably. I have seen them used in the framework Meteor, where they used the package "fibers/future". Fibers is part of Meteor, but I know other implementations exist